# Авто заполнение точек из бд mysql в расчете расстояний Яндекс карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите как в этот код от Яндекс расчет расстояний (api расчет стоимости доставки) сделать авто заполнение точек от и куда их бд MySql? Просто в жс коде точки я указал, все работает, только нужно эти точки брать из бд.

```
routePanel.state.set({
fromEnabled: false,
from: "Москва",
to: "Санкт-Петербург",
type: "auto"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать Ajax'ом обращаться к стороннему скрипту, который будет забирать точки из БД и отдавать, скажем json-структуру вида:

```
{
    from: "Москва",
    to: "Санкт-Петербург"
}
```

Примерно вот это я имею ввиду:

```
jQuery.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
        from: data.from,
        to: data.to,
        type: "auto"
    });
});
```